# Javascript. Replace element "<termref />" with regular "text"

Tags: javascript

I have a document that is filled with text and elements. I looks like this:

```
<document>
<body>
<p>Here is some text</p><p>This is some <termref /> text</p>
</body>
</document>
```

I want to replace `<termref />` with the text "more". The result i would like to get is:

```
<p>Here is some text</p><p>This is some more text</p>
```

I use a third party software so i cannot use jQuery or any other API, just Javascript.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `<termref />` isn't a valid HTML tag. Just because you put the `/` in there isn't going to make it a void element. The browsers will likely consider `text` to be a child of that element, ending up with `<termref> text</termref>`, but I don't know if it'll be consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tag is not valid. But if it wasn't self-closing, you could do it using outerText property:

```
<p>Here is some text</p><p>This is some <termref></termref> text</p>
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("termref")[0].outerText = "more";
    // Or using querySelector
    document.querySelector("termref").outerText = "more";
</script>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bT4CL/) which demonstrates.

If you need to support older IE browsers, you will need to shim your `termref` tag in:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script> document.createElement("termref"); </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Is that IE fix needed for DOM selection? I thought that fix was just for CSS styling.

Comment: It's not only CSS, DOM selection *may* work but I included it anyway just to highlight. I think it can't contain any children on these browsers but not sure if you can call `outerText` on them

Comment: <p>Here is some text <termref> </termref> </p><p>This is some <termref></termref> text</p>   not working

Comment: @SHIN I think it's clear that I'm only selecting one element. The OP will have to determine under what circumstances the element needs replaced and write the code accordingly

Comment: @RGraham i do appreciate your idea and knowledge.

Comment: @user2075124: FYI, Firefox doesn't support `.outerText`. The safest, most compatible way will to swap the node with a new text node using `.replaceChild` from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should set up a program that detects the entire content of your *.html document and sets that content into a string. Then, all you have to do is have a function that detects the substring termref element (stackoverflow doesn't take kindly to inputting raw html elements :P) and replaces it w/ "more". There are many ways to do this efficiently.